# Nexus credentials in Jenkins with sbt

Tags: jenkins, sbt, nexus, credentials

I'm trying to make a nexus job to publish a jar to nexus.  I'm using sbt with scala, and I have a configuration file with the required credentials in it.  I'm having trouble when I run `sbt publish`, it's giving me unauthorized errors.  I need to be able to link my credentials to my sbt build.  I'm trying set the target of my configurations to `~/.ivy2/.credentials` but it doesn't seem to be working.  Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can put all your credential files in a common directory, and add a global configuration file to add all of them in sbt.

~/.sbt/0.13/credentials.sbt

```
credentials ++= (Path.userHome / ".sbt" / "credentials")
  .listFiles
  .collect {
    case f if f.isFile => Credentials(f)
  }
  .toSeq
```

~/.sbt/credentials/my-nexus-repo

```
realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
host=mynexusrepo.com
user=username
password=password
```

~/.sbt/credentials/my-artifactory-repo

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=myartifactoryrepo.com
user=username
password=password
```

Comment: Actually, how would that work on Jenkins?  Someone told me that there could be many servers that jenkins is running on.  Is there a better way to do this than updating everything server with these credentials?

Comment: You have to do it on every jenkins slaves that's going to build your project. In out practice, we keep our building tool's global configurations and a quick setup script in a git repo.

Comment: Can you add where should I place those files, is what is home (`~`, `Path.userHome`) for the Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Like in the [sbt doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html#Credentials):

There are two ways to specify credentials for such a repository:

### Inline

`credentials += Credentials("Some Nexus Repository Manager", "my.artifact.repo.net", "admin", "password123")`

### External File

```
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
```

The credentials file is a properties file with keys realm, host, user, and password. For example:

```
realm=My Nexus Repository Manager
host=my.artifact.repo.net
user=admin
password=admin123
```