# SBT credentials file with multiple realm

Tags: sbt, credentials

We run an artifactory server, that has moved to a different endpoint (`artifactory-b.example.com`). To make it backwards compatible, the old url (`artifactory-a.example.com`) is being proxied to the new one.

However, publishing with sbt uses a `.ivy2/.credentials` file with the following layout

```
realm=Artfactory realm
host=artifactory-a.example.com
user=artifactory-user
password=P4ssw0rdH4sh
```

however, I would like to change this so new builds will publish to the correct endpoint

```
realm=Artfactory realm
host=artifactory-d.example.com
user=artifactory-user
password=P4ssw0rdH4sh
```

Is it possible to add multiple realms in one file? That sbt will try the first, if it does not work (Forbidden|Not Found) the second? So that my `.ivy2/.credentials` file looks like

```
# old instance for backwards compatibility
realm=Artfactory realm
host=artifactory-a.example.com
user=artifactory-user
password=P4ssw0rdH4sh

# New spiffy instance
realm=Artfactory realm
host=artifactory-b.example.com 
user=artifactory-user
password=P4ssw0rdH4sh
```

Anyone any experience with this, or am I bound to using two files, and change the reference in my repo to the second file (i.e. `.ivy2/.credentials2`).

P.S. The realms are in a file, because multiple repos use these credentials to publish.
So important here is that the realms have the same name, only a different endpoint (unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926694/nexus-credentials-in-jenkins-with-sbt)):

Answer (score 17, accepted):

May there is no way to have multiple realms within a credential file, but you could have multiple realms within multiple credential files, each realm in a separate credential file.

In `~/.ivy/.credentials` will be:

```
realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
host=mvn.nexus1.org
user=readonly
password=readonlyPass
```

And in `~/.ivy/.credentials.deploy` will be:

```
realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
host=deploy.nexus2.org
user=deployment
password=deploymentPass
```

So then you will have these lines in your `build.sbt`:

```
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials.deploy")
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that what I want is not possible using a properties file, because that is just not how property files work.

Maybe there is another way, but the solution I want can not be achieved in this way, unfortunately